Объединение записей запроса с приоритетом NULL
Есть задача выбрать записи из таблицы(MSSQL) и сгруппировать их по ID и DT, а так же если у одной из записи с одинаковыми id и DT поле date_end is null, то выбрать эту запись, а если нет такого поля, то выбрать максимальную дату(вывод поля end_date обязателен)
Структура таблицы



ID
DT
date_end




12345
Q2
NULL


12345
Q2
01.01.2023



Пробовал такой запрос, но возвращаются обе записи
select ID,DT,case when date_end is NULL then null else MAX(date_end) end date_end from test
    GROUP BY ID,DT,date_end

Помогает оконная функция FIRST_VALUE, но работает крайне медленно
select ID,DT,date_end from(
   select ID,DT,FIRST_VALUE(date_end) OVER(ORDER BY date_end asc)date_end from test
)g
GROUP BY ID,DT,date_end

Какие ещё есть варианты?
p.s.
Спасибо за ответ @Akina, итоговый запрос получился таким:
select ID, DT, date_end from (
  SELECT ID, DT, date_end,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, DT ORDER BY date_end asc) rn
  FROM test
)cte
WHERE rn = 1;

Данная конструкция работает на много быстрее чем с FIRST_VALUE

Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL? пункты 5 и 3.

сгруппировать их по ID и DT Точно надо именно сгруппировать? дальше почему-то требуется получение отдельных записей, а не агрегированных данных...

Нужны уникальные записи id+dt+(date_end если есть поле с null, то только его, если нет то максимальную дату)

Это - не группировка!!! Это - обычная выборка по условию/признаку.

Скорее всего, речь идёт о тривиальном
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ID, DT, date_end,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, DT ORDER BY COALESCE(date_end, '9999-12-31') DESC) rn
  FROM test 
)
SELECT ID, DT, date_end
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;

fiddle

Ещё один вариант без CTE. Заменяем NULL на максимально возможную дату, берём максимум, и если он получился это максимальной датой, то заменяем обратно на NULL.
SELECT ID, DT, NULLIF(COALESCE(date_end, '9999-12-31'), '9999-12-31') AS date_end
FROM test
GROUP BY ID, DT


Получается какое то двойное преобразование. На больших объёмах думаю будут проблемы с производительностью.

@IvanChuzhmakov, при отсутствии подходящих индексов, ORDER BY в оконных функциях потребует куда больше ресурсов чем детерминированная скалярная функция, которая даже в плане не отображается в связи с незначительностью "стоимости"
